# How to perform a rolling window on a pandas DataFrame, whereby each row consists nan values that should not be replaced?

Tags: pandas, types, multiple-columns, nan, rolling-computation

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 2, 4, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,1],
                 [0, 1, 2 ,np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,np.nan,1],
                 [0, 2, 2 ,np.nan, 2, np.nan,1,1]])
```

With output:

```
   0  1  2    3    4    5    6  7
0  0  1  2    4  NaN  NaN  NaN  1
1  0  1  2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1
2  0  2  2  NaN    2  NaN    1  1
```

with dtypes:

```
    df.dtypes

0      int64
1      int64
2      int64
3    float64
4    float64
5    float64
6    float64
7      int64
```

Then the underneath rolling summation is applied:

```
df.rolling(window = 7, min_periods =1, axis = 'columns').sum()
```

And the output is as follows:

```
     0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
0  0.0  1.0  3.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0
1  0.0  1.0  3.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  4.0
2  0.0  2.0  4.0  NaN  2.0  2.0  3.0  5.0
```

I notice that the rolling window stops and starts again whenever the `dtype` of the next column is different.

I however have a dataframe whereby all columns are of the same `object` type.

```
df = df.astype('object')
```

which has output:

```
     0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
0  0.0  1.0  3.0  7.0  7.0  7.0  7.0  8.0
1  0.0  1.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  4.0
2  0.0  2.0  4.0  4.0  6.0  6.0  7.0  8.0
```

My desired output however, stops and starts again after a `nan` value appears. This would look like:

```
     0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
0  0.0  1.0  3.0  7.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  8.0
1  0.0  1.0  3.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  Nan  4.0
2  0.0  2.0  4.0  NaN  6.0  NaN  7.0  8.0
```

I figured there must be a way that NaN values are not considered but also not filled in with values obtained from the rolling window.

Anything would help!

Comment: I'd recommending opening an issue in their GitHub page (https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues). Of course there are many workarounds available, but It looks like this should work out-of-the-box (at least for int/float Dfs)

Comment: Okay will post the same question on github. But could you tell me what workarounds are available?@rafaelc

Answer (score 0):

Workaround is:

Where are the nan-values located:

```
nan = df.isnull()
```

Apply the rolling window.

```
df = df.rolling(window = 7, min_periods =1, axis = 'columns').sum()
```

Only show values labeled as false.

```
df[~nan]
```